# How do I make images responsive with pure css?

Tags: css, wordpress, twitter-bootstrap

I have a Wordpress menu that I've made the tabs background images. I am trying to get the images to scale down when the `.wrapper` scales down and keep them in a horizontal row and avoid javascript and/or media queries or navwalker class as I'm using bootstrap.

This is what the menu looks like full scale:

[image]

Here is my code for my `.wrapper` and for a one out of the 9 menu-items and the nav class and logo structure. Please note I'm trying to apply the same concept to the logo.

I am using html5blank and Wordpress menu.

```
<div class="nav" role="navigation">
    <?php html5blank_nav(); ?>
</div>
```

here is the html it renders of one of the 9 `<li>`'s ( that I'm styling in the css )

```
<li id="menu-item-1688" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-1688"><a href="http://myUrl.com/blog/">Blog</a></li>


.wrapper {
    max-width:1280px;
    width:95%;
    margin:0 auto;
    position:relative;
}


  .logo {
        float:left;
        width:145px;
        height:157px;
    }

    .nav {
        float:left;
        padding-top:11px;
    }
    .nav ul {
        padding:0;
        margin:0;
    }
    .nav ul li {
        float:left;
        list-style-type:none;
        padding:0;
        margin:0;
    }

    li#menu-item-1688 a {
        display:block;
        background:url('img/ksl_news.png');
        background-repeat:no-repeat;
        width:110px;
        height:119px;
        color:transparent;
        margin-top:27px;
    }
```

Comment: Use percentages for the dimensions of the images.

Comment: @user2684452 Could you please post some of the actual HTML markup that `html5blank_nav()` produces? Even better if you can paste that into a jsfiddle or something so we don't need to put as much effort in to help you.

The reason I ask, is that it really doesn't matter at all that the markup comes from wordpress - the problem is getting the presentation correct for what you're after, so if you can skip the stuff that doesn't matter and boil it down to simple html/css/javascript examples here, you'll get an answer much faster :)

Answer (score 1):

You can use a quirk of the padding property to do this: the values for padding-top/padding-bottom when specified as percentages are calculated based on the width of the element (this also applies for margins).

Minimal example:

```
a {
    background: url('https://i.stack.imgur.com/4kaLj.png');
    background-size: contain;
    display: block;
    padding-top: 12.6324%;
}
```

The `12.6324%` comes from the aspect ratio of your image: `height/width*100` =  `310/2454*100` = `12.6324%`.

`display: block;` causes the element to take 100% width of it's container. Together, this solves your problem, as long as you know the aspect ratio of your images so you can calculate these percentages, this will work.

[Jsfiddle example.](http://jsfiddle.net/L4qm5x89/)

Comment: Really cool. I see how you got that to work but doesn't work in my situation. I tried padding-top, padding-bottom, taking away background-repeat. Nothing was affected. Could have to do with these being menu items and wrapped in other structure?  li#menu-item-1688 a {
    background:url('img/ksl_news.png');
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    width:110px;
    height:119px;
    color:transparent;
    margin-top:27px;
    padding-top:92.4369%;
    background-size: contain;
    display: block;
}

Comment: @user2684452 Yep - it definitely could be. If you edit your question to include a minimal example on jsfiddle or plunkr or something, I'd be happy to help further - it's hard to guess the exact cause of your issue without a full example and all related markup/styles.

Having said that - my current guess is that it's not working because you're providing a width along with the code from my example. This trick relies on usage of `display: block` and `width: auto` - and will not work otherwise. Try setting the width you want on the parent item of your a tag and using `width: auto` on your a tag.

Comment: Although - after I read it again, I now realised I completely mis-understood your question. I'll post a new answer shortly for you :)

Comment: @user2684452 New answer posted :)

Answer (score 1):

So here's an odd approach to this - using `display: table` in order to avoid needing to know the number of menu items you'll have. It's not quite perfect - as the images can sometimes be a pixel off in size, but if this works for you then great :)

HTML:

```
<div class="container">
    <nav class="nav">
        <ul>
            <li class="logo"><a href="/"><img src="//placehold.it/145x157" /></a></li>
            <li><a href="/"><img src="//placehold.it/110x119" /></a></li>
            <li><a href="/"><img src="//placehold.it/110x119" /></a></li>
            <li><a href="/"><img src="//placehold.it/110x119" /></a></li>
            <li><a href="/"><img src="//placehold.it/110x119" /></a></li>
            <li><a href="/"><img src="//placehold.it/110x119" /></a></li>
            <li><a href="/"><img src="//placehold.it/110x119" /></a></li>
            <li><a href="/"><img src="//placehold.it/110x119" /></a></li>
            <li><a href="/"><img src="//placehold.it/110x119" /></a></li>
            <li><a href="/"><img src="//placehold.it/110x119" /></a></li>
        </ul>

    </nav>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.nav {
    display: table;
    width: 100%;
}

.nav ul {
    display: table-row;
}

.nav li {
    list-style: none;
    padding: 0px;
    margin: 0px;
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: bottom;
}

.nav img {
    max-width: 100%;
    border: solid 1px #000;
}
```

[JSFiddle Example.](http://jsfiddle.net/b8dg1Lvd/2/)

---

However if the slight difference in cell size is a problem for you (it is quite noticable), but you are happy to have a hard-coded requirement in css of the number of items in your menu, try using the same markup with the followng CSS instead:

```
.nav ul {
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
    font-size: 0px;
}

.nav li {
    list-style: none;
    padding: 0px;
    margin: 0px;
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: bottom;
    max-width: 9%;
}

.nav li.logo {
    max-width: 11%;
}

.nav img {
    max-width: 100%;
    border: solid 1px #000;
}
```

[Jsfiddle example.](http://jsfiddle.net/b8dg1Lvd/1/)

Comment: I'll try the styles, but not sure this will work in terms of html structure, as I'm using Wordpress menu.

Comment: Please post your HTML structure in as part of your question if you have specific requirements. CSS is not enough for me to guess the HTML structure.